# How can I get past this problem recreating a pg_logical subscription?

Tags: postgresql, pglogical

I'm having a problem dropping and creating subscriptions - I think these messages are saying it exists on the replica and not the primary:

```
db=#   CREATE SUBSCRIPTION sub 
db-#   CONNECTION 'dbname=db host=some.domain.com user=logical_replicator password=xxxxxxx' 
db-#   PUBLICATION pub;
ERROR:  subscription "sub" already exists
db=# DROP subscription sub;
ERROR:  could not drop the replication slot "sub" on publisher
DETAIL:  The error was: ERROR:  replication slot "sub" does not exist
```

How can I get this subscription recreated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-dropsubscription.html):

```
db =# ALTER SUBSCRIPTION sub DISABLE;
ALTER SUBSCRIPTION
db =# ALTER SUBSCRIPTION sub SET (slot_name=NONE);
ALTER SUBSCRIPTION
db =# drop subscription sub;
```